# Chart.Js Remove Label below the title

Tags: chart.js

How to remove this label below the title of the bar chart?

```
//MARITAL STATUS 
                var marital_status=obj.marital_status;
                //alert(sex.Male);
                var ctx2 = document.getElementById('marital_status_chart').getContext('2d');
                var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: ["Single","Married", "Widowed","Separated","Others"],
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [marital_status.Single, marital_status.Married, marital_status.Widowed,marital_status.Separated,marital_status.Others],
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            backgroundColor: my_backgroundColors,
                            hoverBackgroundColor: my_hoverBackgroundColor,
                            hoverBorderColor: my_hoverBorderColor,
                        }]
                    },
                    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
                    options: {
                        plugins: {
                            datalabels: {
                                color: 'black'
                            },
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Marital Status'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

[image]

Comment: No. I tried this already. Placed the `legend:{display:false}`  inside the `options{}`.

Comment: I see now. It is moved to `options.plugins.legend`.

Comment: I'm glad you could find it! Yeah I think there were some major changes to the api between versions